# How to programatically upload document on Google Docs?

Tags: c#, api, upload, google-docs

I building a small application uploading documents on Google Docs.
Is there any API like Goolge API (Ver2) for same?

Is it possible by using  Goolge API (Ver2) ?

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has an API for docs posted online:  http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html

Check out their developer guides for information specific to .NET:  http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/developers_guide.html

Comment: now i facing this issue: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839228/unable-upload-large-file-size-on-google-docs