# Unable to upload large files to Google Docs

Tags: c#, upload, google-docs

I am uploading documents on Google Docs as:

```
DocumentsService myService = new DocumentsService("");
myService.setUserCredentials("username@domain.com", password );
DocumentEntry newEntry = myService.UploadDocument(@"C:\Sample.txt", "Sample.txt");
```

But when I try to upload a file of 3 MB I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException'
>   occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll
>   Additional information: Execution of
>   request failed:
>   http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full

How can I upload large files to Google Docs?
I am using Google API ver 2.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are attempting to upload a .txt file.

This will be converted to a Google Docs "Document" file.

Files that can be converted are limited to 1 Million characters of (2Mb in size).

If you change the extension type to something that is not recognised by Google Docs (for example .log), it will allow you to upload a file of up to 10Gb! Although the free account only has 1Gb of storage for files.

This will allow you to store and retrieve files via your application, but the user will not be able to directly modify them with the Google docs interface, although  they can still download it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on size of file being uploaded:
http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603
Note that there is a conversion done to html and that post-conversion size id the limit.

If you could post some more specifics I could probably come up with a creative solution. What comes to mind so far are:
How about break document up into smaller documents and link then in either file name or actual link in document.
Pre process the document into streamlined text (not sure what kind of files you need to upload.
Upload as stored files and maybe have a google doc that loads the content in an iframe or something similar.
But yeah, if you give me more details, I can think it out if you like.

Comment: yes even i thought of sending data in chunk.
But does Google API(Ver 2) support chunk data migration?
I am using : UploadDocument() method.(as shown in my post).
How can send data in chunk using this method? or is there any other way?

Comment: just to cover my basis, are you able to upload a small file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to findout terms and conditions, if they support larger files. Also there will be timeouts set in the library, see ifyou can increase your timeout values in your GData.Client

Answer (score 0):

You have a file limit of 500Kb for documents to be converted.

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603

Comment: but i have seen in "GoogleEmailUploader" they are uploading mails of large size.So must be some way in which we can upload mails with large attachment.

And in my case i am unable to upload mail of 2 MB size also.