# How to increase timeout values in GData.Client (Google API Ver 2)?

Tags: c#, file, upload, google-docs

I am trying to upload a 2MB file on Google Docs.
In one of [forum reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839228/unable-to-upload-large-files-to-google-docs) user suggested me to  increase timeout values in GData.Client.

But how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to increase the timeout, use google's [Resumable Upload API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/resumable_upload.html) - it was designed specifically for this purpose.