# tool or library for Google docs file upload

Tags: api, upload, google-docs

I need a simple library or tool with which I can upload arbitrary files (other than the explicitly supported formats, like .doc, .docx, .xls, .pdf, .txt, .ppt etc.) to Google Docs. The Perl module WWW::Google::Docs::Upload doesn't work, I get an exception (`Link not found at /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8/WWW/Google/Docs/Upload.pm line 39`; it's from 2008). Any programming language which is easy to run on Linux should be fine.

The responses [How to programatically upload document on Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838968/how-to-programatically-upload-document-on-google-docs) suggest using the API directly. Is there a tool or library which is a convenient wrapper around the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload arbitrary files by automating the Web UI.
See how to do this here: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/googledocs-rse/wiki/UploadAnyFileToGoogleDocs

Answer (score 1):

The project you want is called `googlecl` - see http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/Manual

Comment: Except that uploading non-supported file formats doesn't work with googlecl, because Google explicitly forbids uploading non-supported file formats using the API.

Answer (score 0):

The googlecl (google command line) tool allows you to upload docs.

http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/